# az cli version failing with error required python3 even if 3.8.1/3.6.4 installed

Tags: azure-cli

1. Hi team ,we have python 3.6.4 /3.8.1 installed however we are not
   able install az cli 2.14

   python

   Python 3.6.4 (default, Oct 29 2020, 22:55:45)  [GCC 4.8.5 20150623
   (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or
   "license" for more information.

   > > > 

   below are the symlink created in /usr/bin/

   ls -lrt |grep python

   -rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root       11312 Apr 27  2018 abrt-action-analyze-python
   -rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root        7216 Jul 13  2018 python2.7 lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root          15 Oct 21 21:20
   ambari-python-wrap -> /usr/bin/python lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root
   24 Oct 29 22:23 python3 -> /usr/local/bin/python3.6 lrwxrwxrwx.   1
   root root           7 Oct 29 22:23 python -> python3 lrwxrwxrwx.   1
   root root           9 Oct 29 23:20 python2 -> python2.7

   **we followed below steps** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-yum?view=azure-cli-latest

   **error**

   sudo  yum install azure-cli

   Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks Repository epel is listed
   more than once in the configuration Loading mirror speeds from
   cached hostfile

   1. epel: ftp.plusline.net Resolving Dependencies
      --> Running transaction check
      ---> Package azure-cli.x86_64 0:2.13.0-1.el7 will be upd
   2. List item

   ated
   ---> Package azure-cli.x86_64 0:2.14.0-1.el7 will be an update
   --> Processing Dependency: python3 for package: azure-cli-2.14.0-1.el7.x86_64
   --> Processing Dependency: libpython3.6m.so.1.0()(64bit) for package: azure-cli-2.14.0-1.el7.x86_64

   1. List item

   --> Running transaction check
   ---> Package azure-cli.x86_64 0:2.14.0-1.el7 will be an update
   --> Processing Dependency: python3 for package: azure-cli-2.14.0-1.el7.x86_64
   ---> Package python36-libs.x86_64 0:3.6.8-2.el7.ius will be installed
   --> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 3.6 for package: python36-libs-3.6.8-2.el7.ius.x86_64
   --> Running transaction check
   ---> Package azure-cli.x86_64 0:2.14.0-1.el7 will be an update
   --> Processing Dependency: python3 for package: azure-cli-2.14.0-1.el7.x86_64
   ---> Package python36.x86_64 0:3.6.8-2.el7.ius will be installed
   --> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: Package: azure-cli-2.14.0-1.el7.x86_64 (azure-cli)
   Requires: python3  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
   ** Found 2 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows: azure-cli-2.13.0-1.el7.x86_64 has missing requires of
   libpython3.6m.so.1.0()(64bit) azure-cli-2.13.0-1.el7.x86_64 has
   missing requires of python3

   We are trying to upgrade from az cli 2.13 which has other issues
   that we aare trying to avoid.

Comment: Did you actually follow steps 1,2 and 3?

Comment: Have you tried running `az upgrade` since you already are on 2.13.0?

Comment: I tried running az upgrade  but it fails with the same error  @bhargavi

Comment: Yes @RoadRunner

Comment: @Jatinchoudhury How was the current version installed? Please use the same method (as installation) to upgrade as well.